# Query to fetch values corresponding to the last effective date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have 3 tables in my database that need to be joined in a query and they are as follows:

ResStayDate.dbo

```
ResaID    StayDate        Rate   
 50       2015-01-20      235.00
 50       2015-01-21      235.00
 50       2015-01-22      235.00
 50       2015-01-23      235.00
 54       2015-02-10      200.00
 54       2015-02-11      200.00
 65       2015-03-12      155.00
 65       2015-03-13      155.00
 67       2015-04-10      290.00
 67       2015-04-11      290.00
 67       2015-04-12      290.00
```

ResStay.dbo

```
 ResaID    Currency
  50        USD
  54        USD
  65        EUR
  67        EUR
```

ExchangeRate.dbo

```
Currency     ExRate     EffectiveDate
  USD        28.00       2015-01-20
  EUR        40.00       2015-01-20
  USD        30.00       2015-01-22
  EUR        40.00       2015-01-22
  USD        30.00       2015-03-13
  EUR        40.00       2015-03-13
  USD        30.00       2015-04-11
  EUR        42.00       2015-04-11
```

The output that I want my query to give is as follows:

```
 ResaID       StayDate    Rate      ExRate        Revenue 
   50       2015-01-20   235.00     28.00          6580.00
   50       2015-01-21   235.00     28.00          6580.00
   50       2015-01-22   235.00     30.00          7050.00
   50       2015-01-23   235.00     30.00          7050.00
   54       2015-02-10   200.00     30.00          6000.00
   54       2015-02-11   200.00     30.00          6000.00
   65       2015-03-12   155.00     40.00          6200.00
   65       2015-03-13   155.00     40.00          6200.00
   67       2015-04-10   290.00     40.00         11600.00
   67       2015-04-11   290.00     42.00         12180.00
   67       2015-04-12   290.00     42.00         12180.00
```

Revenue is calculated as follows: `ResStayDate.Rate * ExRate` (by matching the `Currency` in `ResStay.dbo` with the `Currency` value in `ExchangeRate.dbo`).

I have progressed this far with my query, but I am stuck with how to match the `ResStayDate.StayDate` with the `ExchangeRate.EffectiveDate` so that the query can use the proper `ExRate` of the `Currency`. 
My problem lies in that the `ExchangeRate` table does not list the values of the currency on a daily basis but only when there is a change in the `ExRate` of a `Currency`.

As such, the `ExRate` of a `Currency` is effective until the date of the next change and so on. I need to match my `StayDate` in the `ResStayDate` table with the corresponding `ExRate` value of that `Currency` in the `ExchangeRate` table.

So, my draft query as at now looks like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM 

 (
 (SELECT ResaID, 
        StayDate,
        Rate,
        (?????) As [Revenue]
 FROM ResStayDate)a

LEFT JOIN ResStay b ON b.ResaID = a.ResaID
LEFT JOIN ExRate  c ON c.Currency = b.Currency

)xy
```

I can't figure out how to plug in the `ExRate` in the query so that I can use the equation to get the `Revenue` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `CROSS APPLY` here.
Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1324f/4/0).

Add index to `ExchangeRate` on `(Currency, EffectiveDate)` and it would be efficient.

Make sure that you have a value in `ExchangeRate` for each currency with `EffectiveDate` before the first date in `ResStayDate`, otherwise these dates would not get any matching rows in `CROSS APPLY` and they will not appear in the final result. If your data may have historical values that don't have exchange rates, use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`. In this case you'll get NULLs and you'll at least see that something is wrong, rather than silently not having rows in the result.

```
SELECT
  ResStayDate.ResaID
  ,ResStayDate.StayDate
  ,ResStayDate.Rate
  ,CA.ExRate
  ,ResStayDate.Rate * CA.ExRate AS Revenue
FROM
  ResStayDate
  INNER JOIN ResStay ON ResStay.ResaID = ResStayDate.ResaID
  CROSS APPLY
  (
      SELECT TOP(1) ExchangeRate.ExRate
      FROM ExchangeRate
      WHERE
        ExchangeRate.Currency = ResStay.Currency
        AND ExchangeRate.EffectiveDate <= ResStayDate.StayDate
      ORDER BY ExchangeRate.EffectiveDate DESC
  ) AS CA
ORDER BY ResaID, StayDate;
```

Comment: Wow! That's fantastic! Just what I wanted. Thanks a lot!.

Comment: Thanks also for the OUTER APPLY tip! Indeed, I got NULL for a particular currency called "MUR" that is never affected by a change since it always remains at 1.00 (and hence does not appear in the ExchangeRate table).
Is there a way to handle this case? May be with a CASE statement? Grateful if you could provide some help.

Comment: Yes, you can use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY` and then simply use `ISNULL(CA.ExRate, 1)` instead of `CA.ExRate`. This makes all instances when exchange rate is not available for some reason to force the rate to be equal to 1. But, personally, I would not put such code in the production. If the data is not available, it means that it has to be verified and entered, rather than silently assuming something. In the case that you mentioned I would add one row into `ExchangeRate` with `Currency='MUR'`, `ExRate=1.0`, `EffectiveDate='2000-01-01'` or `1900-01-01`.

Comment: Even if `MUR` is your native currency and it doesn't really require a conversion (right now, that is), still it makes sense to have it in `ExchangeRate` table: 1) to simplify this and possibly other queries and logic 2) has that currency ever gone through the process of [redenomination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redenomination)? Will it never happen? You don't know. You can easily handle it with the same `ExchangeRate` table.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I fully agree with you on adding MUR in the Exchange Rate table.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do like below, also use `ISNULL()` function

```
SELECT a.ResaID, 
        a.StayDate,
        a.Rate,
        a.Rate * ISNULL(c.ExRate,0) As [Revenue]
 FROM ResStayDate a
LEFT JOIN ResStay b ON b.ResaID = a.ResaID
LEFT JOIN ExchangeRate  c ON c.Currency = b.Currency;
```